# How to join multiple tables using max() on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, queryselector

I just start learning Laravel and i got stuck on this issue. How could i do this select using QuerySelector or Eloquent on Laravel ?

[That is the result i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cMAY.png)

Thats what i came of so far:

```
$produtos = \DB::table('produtos AS p')
   ->leftJoin('produtos_fotos AS pf','pf.produto_id','=','p.id')
   ->leftJoin('produtos_grade AS pg','pg.produto_id','=','p.id')
     ->select('p.id','p.referencia','p.descricao','p.preco','p.ratings',
                            'p.categorias_produtos as categoria','p.promocao','p.genero', 'p.cabedal as materialCabedal','p.solado as materialSolado', 'p.altura_salto AS alturaSalto','pf.url','pf.nome_foto','min(pg.tamanho) as tam_min', 'max(pg.tamanho) as tam_max')
    ->where(['p.fornecedor_id' => $idFornecedor])
    ->groupBy('p.id')
    ->get())
```

But i got an error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
>   found: 1054 Unknown column 'min(pg.tamanho)' in 'field list'
>
> Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello in laravel if you want to use raw expression in a query. you need to use [DB::raw method](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-expressions)

in your case change to below will work.

```
$produtos = \DB::table('produtos AS p')
     ->leftJoin('produtos_fotos AS pf','pf.produto_id','=','p.id')
     ->leftJoin('produtos_grade AS pg','pg.produto_id','=','p.id')
     ->select(
          'p.id',
          'p.referencia',
          'p.descricao',
          'p.preco',
          'p.ratings',
          'p.categorias_produtos as categoria',
           'p.promocao',
           'p.genero',
           'p.cabedal as materialCabedal',
           'p.solado as materialSolado',
           'p.altura_salto AS alturaSalto',
           'pf.url', 
           'pf.nome_foto',
                DB::raw('min(pg.tamanho) as tam_min'),
                 DB::raw('max(pg.tamanho) as tam_max')
      )
      ->where(['p.fornecedor_id' => $idFornecedor])
      ->groupBy('p.id')
      ->get())
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @sok hai. I've tried your code, but now i getting this error: 
'Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'fornecedores.p.referencia' isn't in GROUP BY'. I supose the 'groupBy' condition should be elsewhere, but i dont know how to do.

Comment: @LucasFerreira this case from mysql. 
you can see this link for solution: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14997#issuecomment-242129087